# Magento and urlencoded urls

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I have some links in google like this:

**/%3Fcat%3D9%26dir%3Dasc%26limit%3D10%26mode%3Dlist%26order%3Dprice**

which equals this link (urldecoded):

**/?cat=5&dir=desc&order=price&p=2**

If we go by url **http://my-shop.com/%3Fcat%3D9%26dir%3Dasc%26limit%3D10%26mode%3Dlist%26order%3Dprice**, then Magento shows us 404 error

How can i get Magento redirect those bad urls to their respective urldecoded correct urls?

Magento version 1.7.0.2

Thanks for your time

Comment: What makes these "bad urls"? See the lack of 404 at [http://demo.magentocommerce.com/?%3Fcat%3D9%26dir%3Dasc%26limit%3D10%26mode%3Dlist%26order%3Dprice](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/?%3Fcat%3D9%26dir%3Dasc%26limit%3D10%26mode%3Dlist%26order%3Dprice) - perhaps more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the url, not the redirect. I hope this is clear? You have to remove this urls from your shop and from google.

After that, I don't think, there is a good way to do this, because you try to fix an uncommon error.

The magento way might be adding rules to the htaccess or adding the rule to the Magento internal rewrite table, but both solutions don't handle generic rules or regex, which solves this (with the htaccess I'm not sure).

So, I would fix the "bad url creation" problem and hack the index.php at the beginning, check wether such an url is requested, decode it and redirect to the page, `die();`